# Unable to share Content on Facebook through Android App

Tags: android

I have an android app in which i am using Facebook Android SDK to post content from my application to Facebook Wall. My code was working perfectly till i updated the Facebook app on my phone. Since that time, whenever i try to post content on Facebook, i get the login screen with the "Loading" option and after a few seconds, nothing happens. Here is the code which i am using

On Facebook Button CLick

```
if(isOnline())
        {
        mFacebook = new Facebook("APP ID");


        mFacebook.authorize(this,new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, new AuthorizeListener());

        }
```

The Code for Authorize listener is

```
class AuthorizeListener implements DialogListener {


 public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

       //  Handle a successful login
    postOnWall("My wall text");


      }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {



    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {




    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {



    }
    }
```

After debugging i found that the OnComplete method is not being called after calling the authorize function and there is also no exception. This was working perfectly till i update the Facebook app on my Android phone.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `Facebook.authorizeCallback` in your Activity's `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  // ... anything else your app does onActivityResult ...
}
```

For the details, carefully read [this page](https://github.com/iamnoah/facebook-android-sdk).